# Mode is not changing in detailsview

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

in details  view once   i click  edit mode. all the controls are getting into  edit mode. i make the changes  and  give update data is updated in database . but still all the controls  are in edit mode only **"actaully once we  give  click then   update then  i   should  again  gone to read only mode means  all the values  should again  be  showing  in label  field"**

i am doing  this in .cs  file only 
no sqldatadource is  used or object  datasource

right now this  feature is not happening to me.  what is the issue here?

looking forward  for an  solution
 thank you

Comment: itemupdated event fired after itemuupadating. can you elaborate more what you require actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you aren't using any built-in code to do the update, you probably need to change the display mode manually during your update.

```
myDetailsView.ChangeMode( DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly );
```

Comment: ya  added this line  of  code   in ItemUpdating  event that is after i do  update  to  database:
{ 
myDetailsView.ChangeMode( DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly );
}
  but i  get an error telling that as  you are in edit mode  you cannot  do  readonly here